# RSpec match_array with hashes

Tags: ruby, rspec

I was wondering if there's a way to achieve what I want with RSpec. So I want to test an array of hashes that looks similar to this one:

```
array_example =
 [
  {
   id: 1, 
   link: "www.some-link.com/path_im_not_interested_in"
  }, 
  {
   id: 2, 
   link: "www.example-link.com/another_useless_path"
  }
 ]
```

I want to do integration test in which I won't include those paths in links. I'm only interested in checking if `www.some-link.com` and `www.example-link.com` are present in those hashes in array. Something like this:

```
expect(array_example).to match_array(
 [
  {
   id: 1, 
   link: "www.some-link.com"
  }, 
  {
   id: 2, 
   link: "www.example-link.com"
  }
 ]
```

But this one obviously won't work. Is there a way to achieve what I want? I would like to avoid using custom matchers.

Comment: It sounds like you only want to test the `link:`, ie. you want to ignore the `id:`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use composed matchers:

```rb
expect(array_example)
  .to contain_exactly(
    a_hash_including(id: 1, link: a_string_including("www.some-link.com")),
    a_hash_including(id: 2, link: a_string_including("www.example-link.com"))
  )
```

See https://rspec.info/blog/2014/01/new-in-rspec-3-composable-matchers/ for more information.

The argument of `a_hash_including` does not have to cover the whole hash, it will only check the keys you are passing.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!